# What is the difference between "He's not good at English" and "He's no good at English"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

According to my study "**no good**" means "not any good" or "not good at all".

So "**He's no good at English**" means "**He's not any good at English**" or "**He's not good at English at all**".

However, "**no good**" also means "not very useful or effective".

"**He's no good at English**" might mean he knows some English but his English is not so effective.

What is the difference between "**He's not good at English**" and "**He's no good at English**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No good means something has no use or value, and has no potential of becoming good. Not good means something is bad or undesirable. [Source: Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/e/not-good-vs-no-good/)

So "no good at English" means he is not good at English *and* has **no potential of becoming good**. "Not good at English" means he is simply not good at it.

> It would be rude and unkind to describe someone as no good at a subject, unless you knew them very well. - @KateBunting

Comment: It would be rude and unkind to describe someone as **no good at** a subject, unless you knew them very well.